# How to bridge two wifi networks, one private, one with internet connection, one linux PC with connections to both

Tags: networking, bridge

I have a local wifi "hotspot" with various devices on it. I have a second hotspot which provides internet access (android).

I have a Ubuntu PC with two wireless cards - one connected to the android hotspot for internet access and the other connected to the private hotspot.

How do I configure my linux PC and other linux devices on the private network to allow temporary access to the linux devices on the private network?

Comment: The solution is here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530269/how-to-share-internet-hotspot-access-to-a-network-on-a-second-wifi-adapter/530285#530285

Comment: To allow temporary access to the linux devices on the private network *to whom*? What should be allowed to access your linux devices?